# I want to add delay in my android app

Tags: android, time, delay, gyroscope

I am coding an android app that takes data from gyroscope and measures the leaning angle of the bicycle. I want to display a warning sign if it leans more than 35°. Now, I want to add a condition that says if the leaning angle is greater than 35° and time is more than one second then display the warning. The problem is that I am unable to figure out how to implement this time logic. I am a newbie Android developer.

if (angle > 35){
     SHOW WARNING
}

Comment: Please post the code you have. you could save the first time it is above 35 and compare the time, if the difference in time is someamount show the warning.

Answer (score 0):

you could start your gyro code after a delay.

try something like

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {

            // your code here

        }
    }, 1000);
```